# Why does buffer capacity of tartrate buffer generally decrease as the buffer pH increases?

Tags: acid-base, ph

[image]

From what I see, the buffer capacity of tartrate buffer is generally decreasing as buffer pH increases. Why is this? Also, does this mean that tartrate buffer doesn't have a maximum buffer capacity at pH=pKa?

Or is there a more reliable source where I can get the buffer capacity vs. buffer pH graph for buffers of tartaric acid? This image is from a blog, and I can't find the real source of this image, even with Google image search.

Comment: See: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274826340_Determination_of_titratable_acidity_in_white_wine

Comment: @MaxW I have seen that source, but for some reason the equation they give for their monoprotic buffer capacity is very different from what is given here (http://www.chembuddy.com/?left=pH-calculation&right=pH-buffer-capacity) and the equation for their diprotic buffer capacity gives extremely high values as [H+]/Kw, which is a part of the equation, gives, for example, 10^10, when pH = 4.0. I'm not sure why there's such a big difference from other sources, seeing that the unit are both mol/L/pH. Or am I mistaken about the units being the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the maximum buffer capacity is at $\ce{pK_a}$ . The tartaric acid is somewhat special for 2 reasons:

1. It is a diprotic acid with both $\ce{pK_a}$ very close, with the $\ce{pK_{a1}}$ rather low, being affected by the reason 2. :

   $$\ce{pK_{a1}}=2.89,\ce{pK_{a2}}= 4.40 (L+)$$
2. The solution buffer capacity (not limited to presence of specific buffer substances) generally increases toward $\ce{pH}=0$. It means, the buffer capacity is not given by concentration of  of conjugated acid and base, but also by concentration of $\ce{H+}$ itself.
   That in large extent masks the $\ce{pK_a}$ maximum. It means, at a slope, a local peak must be big enough to be a peak.

Comment: So can the maximum buffer capacity of tartaric acid only be determined experimentally? I've seen a lot of sources that state that tartaric acid is special because of the first reason you've mentioned, but no source actually states what the buffer capacity would look like graphed against buffer pH. Also, the second reason is slightly confusing. Why does buffer capacity generally increase toward pH=0? Could you expand a bit?

Comment: It can be computed. But you may realize there is no maximum.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with buffers -- could you explain why there's a maximum "given by the solubility of the tartaric acid?"

Comment: How would you compute it?

Comment: I deleted the note, as I missed the graph legend. Imagine a slope. If the slope is tilted enough, and if there is a peak small enough, there is no maximum ( or the maximum is not significant) .

Comment: It might be me, but I'm having a hard time imagining that in my head. I do wish there was a way to upload images in the comments. Is the slope you've mentioned a slope of that buffer capacity vs buffer pH graph or a tartaric acid titration graph? I'm imagining a infinite linear slope, so I'm not sure where the "peak" is supposed to be either.

Comment: Notice also the citric acid, it is the same case. It does not have maximum for $pK_{a1}$. It is on the slope toward low $pH$, that is common for all solutions. And yes, I mean the slope on the left on the buffer capacity versus pH graph.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I think I'm getting it. I'm wondering, however, if there's a way to generate a better graph through computation or if there's a more reliable source that has the graph for buffer capacity vs. buffer pH.

Comment: It can be created by computation. See also updated answer.

Comment: Could I do the computation myself? I need to be able to generate a more reliable graph. Could you point me to a source? Thank you so much for your patience, by the way.

Comment: **pH dependency of buffer capacity** - Let's make it simple. Buffer capacity is defined as the *moles* necessary to change pH +/- 1 pH unit. So if we have a two solutions of HCl in water, one with a pH of 2 and another with a pH of 5. It is going to take a lot more acid to raise the pH 2 solution to 1, than it will take to raise the pH 5 solution to 4.

Comment: For a diprotic acid see http://www.aqion.de/site/184 You'll need to plug $a_1$ and $a_2$ from formulas (2.3b) and (2.3c) into formula (5.1a)